# Block Ping from a specific IP

Tags: networking, iptables, ufw

I am on a private LAN 192.168.1.0/24. My ip is 192.168.1.3, I want to block **only ping requests** from 192.168.1.2. 
I am running ubuntu 11.10. I found two links

[First](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/) tells how to block an IP but not how to block only ping requests.
[Second](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Enable_PING) tells how to disable ping all together.

Can someone please tell me how to block only ping requests from a specific IP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using iptables is an exellent choice it's a very powerfull firewall feature built in to the Kernel

as root or with sudo:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.100 -p icmp -j DROP
```

will block all ping(icmp requests) from a  the specified IP.

The following to block all ICMP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

Basically omitting the ip will bock ALL ping requests.

to remove the following active firewall rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

change the -A (append) to -D (delete)

```
iptables -D INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

But do you have a good reason to block ICMP?
Usually ICMP is a good thing. It is used for MTU discovery etc. Basically making sure
that you will have a optimized network/Internet experience.

[More info on why you shouldnt block ICMP here](http://www.netheaven.com/pmtu.html)